# OpenCV - Gather featureDetectors and descriptorDetector in a same program

Tags: c++, opencv, matching, feature-descriptor

I would like to do a programm which allow to use SIFT,SURF,ORB (all the features detector) ,differents descriptors and differents matchers.

I would like to run something like this : features("SIFT","SIFT","BruteForce") respectively features("Detector","descriptor","matcher").

Indeed i had done a program before but there are lots of "if". For example "if (detection="SIFT")" 
"if (matcher=="BruteForce")" etc. And therefore my program is not flexible if i want to use a certain detector with another kind of descriptor.

So i found something like that :

```
 featureDetector = FeatureDetector::create( detectorType );
 descriptorExtractor = DescriptorExtractor::create( descriptorType );
 descriptorMatcher = DescriptorMatcher::create( matcherType );
```

It's perfect because i can use a string in a only one function in order to determine which detector,descriptors and matcher i would like to use.

Howewer, i can't change the parameters (i found something like featureDetector.set() but without documentation) and therefore the result is pretty bad...It takes time to compute for only one picture and keypoints are not accuracy.

Even SIFT take less time than SURF !

Whereas,in my first program, when i used

```
detector=new SiftFeatureDetector(nfeatureSift,nOctaveLayerSift,contrastThresholdSift,edgeThresholdSift,sigmaSift);
```

The result was better  ! (because i probably changed the parameters).

So how can i solve that ? 
Maybe, it's a better solution to do what i've done before but it's so heavy because i have to do a lot of "If" in order to know which detector i want to use with which detector etc...

What do you think about it ?

Thank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to change the algorithm parameters, use the [`set()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?#algorithm-set) method, which you have already found. The parameters available for each feature detector are not documented, but they are enumerated in OpenCV's source, which you can find [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/features2d/src/features2d_init.cpp), or [the nonfree module](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/nonfree/src/nonfree_init.cpp) for SURF and SIFT.

There is a rough correspondence between the enumerated parameters and the parameters listed for the feature detector's constructor.

#### Example

Given the entry for SIFT:

```
CV_INIT_ALGORITHM(SIFT, "Feature2D.SIFT",
                  obj.info()->addParam(obj, "nFeatures", obj.nfeatures);
                  obj.info()->addParam(obj, "nOctaveLayers", obj.nOctaveLayers);
                  obj.info()->addParam(obj, "contrastThreshold", obj.contrastThreshold);
                  obj.info()->addParam(obj, "edgeThreshold", obj.edgeThreshold);
                  obj.info()->addParam(obj, "sigma", obj.sigma))
```

The names in quotes ( e.g. `"nFeatures"`) are the arguments you would provide to the `name` parameter of `set()`.

Thus, to limit the number of features detected to 500, you would write:

```
featureDetector = FeatureDetector::create( detectorType );
featureDetector->set("nFeatures", 500);
```

which will create a detector with identical parameters as writing:

```
SIFT detector(500);
```

**Note:** If using `set()` to set algorithm parameters, any fields that are listed in the `CV_INIT_ALGORITHM` block but which you do not provide will use the default value.

Comment: Thank you for your complete answer ! It helps me a lot.
concerning the "note", i didn't understand all. you told me that if i change a parameters like featureDetector->set("nFeatures", 500); the others parameters use the default value, that's it ?

Comment: That is correct. If you want to know the default values, you can call `get()` with each parameter name.